# How to add dynamically-named selector to a UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I would like to add targets to UIButtons by dynamically generating the selector names for the buttons as I iterate through a `for` loop. So far, I have an `NSArray` of 3 `UIButtons`:

```
NSArray *buttonArray = @[email, webPage, textMessage];
```

I would like now to do something like:

```
for(UIButton *button in buttonArray){
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(CUSTOM NAME HERE) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

It would be nice if I could dynamically form a custom name based on the name of the button (for example the name of the selector would be the button name + "ButtonProc", but I could also use an `NSArray` containing strings correlating to the selector names. How can I do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`NSSelectorFromString()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSelectorFromString).

```
for(UIButton *button in buttonArray){
    [button addTarget:self action:NSSelectorFromString(CUSTOM NAME HERE) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

Don't forget to add `:` at the end of your selector string if your @IBAction is declared with the `sender` argument.

Comment: Knew it had to be there. Thanks a lot.